# Difference between after create, after save and after commit in rails callbacks

Tags: ruby-on-rails

> The difference between after_create, after_save and after_commit in
> Rails is that:

```
after_save -> is invoked when an object is created and updated.
after_commit -> is called on create, update and destroy.
after_create -> is only called when creating an object.
```

**Is this the only difference among those, or are there any other major differences?**

Comment: well you also have to understand when in the object lifecycle these callbacks are called.  Details are here: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#available-callbacks

Answer (score 0):

You are almost correct. Please read the following phrases too. The core difference between these callbacks is the event they are trigged on and the sequence they are triggered in.

- **After Commit:** Triggers after the object is successfully created, updated, or destroyed.
- **After Create:** Triggers only when the object is created. It triggers just before the data is committed to the database.
- **After Save:** Triggers only when the object is updated or created. It triggers just before the data is committed to the database.